# Updating template files requires sailsjs re-lift

Tags: sails.js

I am facing this peculiar problem with `sailsjs`.

Everytime I update my template file in the `views` folder, and navigate to that page in the browser, it still shows the template that was at the time of `sails lift`.

Earlier, a simple page refresh showed the changes.

Now, in order to view the changes, I have to stop and lift `sails` again. This started happening sometime back.

I am using `Dustjs` templates.

Answer (score 0):

From the dustjs github read me:

"Since JavaScript is cacheable, Dust templates can be sent to a browser once and reused which is not the case with server-side generated JSP pages."

You could find out if this is the case by restarting your browser instead of the server and seeing if that has the same effect.

Comment: Ultimately there's not enough info in the question.  Did the problem correspond with your switch to dustjs?  Are you really using templates or are you really just using the provided sails ejs layouts (templates generally live in assets/templates)?  Did you change your template engine in the views.js config?  Did you configure a Grunt task to compile your dustjs templates (how are they getting created and injected)?

Comment: No, it didn't correspond to the switch. I am really using templates. And they are in views. Yes, i changed the templates engine in the views file to dust. I configured my grunt and it works fine. The first page load is directly rendered on the server. That one carries the old dust template :(

Comment: Take a look at tasks/config/watch.js and make sure that your templates are being watched and that the appropriate grunt task is run when they change.  The initial watch.js file is looking for changes to templates in the assets directory, but since yours are in the views directory they might not be getting updated.